# Как передать значение в поле html через Servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlet

Как получать username из формы и выводить измененное значение в отдельную страницу я понял. Но мне нужно понять как измененное  сервлетом username впихнуть в эту же страницу откуда поступил запрос, например в поле с тегом   с id "result" ???

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="MyServlet" method="GET">
    <p>Add user name: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**сервлет:**

```
public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String surname="Ivanov";

        String username = (String) req.getParameter("username");

        username=username+" "+surname;
        resp.getWriter().println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<html><body><p>" + username + "</p></body></html>");

    }

}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.test.BookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно передать *username* в качестве атрибута запроса

```
req.setAttribute("username", username);
```

На странице *jsp* значение атрибута можно получить следующим образом:

```
${username}
```

Comment: Я знаю как это делается через  jsp, но как видите у меня HTML. Мне интересно как в него передать.

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan в *HTML* Вы никак не передадите. Это статическая страница.